# Power set of an element and the empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What would be the power set of a set $S=\{s,\emptyset\}$? Wouldn't it be $\{s,\emptyset,\{s,\emptyset\}\}$, which has an odd cardinality, and is therefore wrong?

Comment: The power set includes all subsets: $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{s\},\{s,\emptyset\}\}.$

Comment: It is not $s$ but $\{ s \}$ and you have forgotten $\{ ∅ \}$.

Comment: @birna - random question, but are you studying for the math GRE subject test?

Comment: $\{ ∅ \}$ and $\emptyset$ are **not** the same set : the first one has **one** element, while the second has none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the power set of $S$ is the set of all subsets of $S$, so all the members of the power set should be sets themselves. Hence, you get
$$\mathcal{P}(S) = \{\emptyset, \{s\}, \{\emptyset\}, \{s, \emptyset\}\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You got the power set wrong. Note that $s \neq \{s\}$, and $\emptyset \neq \{\emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 0):

While $\emptyset\subset S$ (which is true for any arbitrary set $S$), in this case you have $\emptyset\in S$ and therefore $\{\emptyset\}\subset S$, which gives you a cardinality of 4.